# How can I get languages from the language manager in joomla?

Tags: joomla

How can I get the languages installed in the language manager in joomla, as I know the following:

- getLocal() give for local machine language am not get the language installed in the application
- getname() , getTag()  give you the current language name / tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code returns the current language...

```
$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage();
echo 'Current language is: ' . $lang->getName();
```

By using the below query you can get all the languages installed in Joomla.

```
$db =& JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery(
'SELECT sef, title_native' .
' FROM #__languages' .
' ORDER BY sef ASC'
);
$options = $db->loadObjectList();
```

---

If you installed any languages in joomla it will stored to #__extensions table with params. So you can get all the installed languages from the below query...

```
$db =& JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = "SELECT name FROM #__extensions WHERE type='package'";
            $db->SetQuery($query);
            $options = $db->loadObjectList();
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($options);
```

Comment: i dont need only the current language , i need all languages installed in joomla !

Comment: that will get content languages in language manager , but i need to get installed languages !!

Comment: hey.. what are the languages you installed in joomla it should be stored in this table . So you can get the results.. Right?

Comment: that what i thought , you can try by your self , try install a new language , the run the query you post here , you will get only the default language , and content language NOT the installed language !!

Comment: let me check and see you soon.

Answer (score 3):

From contentlanguage field type:

http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types

```
JLanguage::getKnownLanguages()
```

You get a list like this:

```
Array
(
    [en-GB] => Array
        (
            [name] => English (United Kingdom)
            [tag] => en-GB
            [rtl] => 0
            [locale] => en_GB.utf8, en_GB.UTF-8, en_GB, eng_GB, en, english, english-uk, uk, gbr, britain, england, great britain, uk, united kingdom, united-kingdom
            [firstDay] => 0
            [weekEnd] => 0,6
        )

    [es-ES] => Array
        (
            [name] => Spanish (español)
            [tag] => es-ES
            [rtl] => 0
            [locale] => es_ES.utf8, es_ES.UTF-8, es_ES, spanish
            [weekEnd] => 0,6
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

This line returns an array of published languages

```
$languages = JLanguageHelper::getLanguages();
```